# Powershell: Get-ADComputer from another domain returns OperatingSystem information blank/missing

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0

Trying to list all computers with their OS information that belong to another trusted domain, but OperatingSystem and OperatingSystemVersion returns blank values:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties Name, OperatingSystem, OperatingSystemVersion -SearchBase "" -Server OtherDomain.com.au:3268 | Format-Table Name, OperatingSystem, OperatingSystemVersion
```

Only the Name property is populated.

If I run this, it returns alot of info, but the OS info is all blank:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase "" -Server OtherDomain.com.au:3268
```

If I run this command on the "OtherDomain" it works just fine:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties Name, OperatingSystem, OperatingSystemVersion | Format-Table Name, OperatingSystem, OperatingSystemVersion
```

I get all 3 information I want.  Is there some security issue here that I am encountering when I run it from a different domain?  I can browse through Active Directory Users and Computers (dsa.msc) and see the OS information of computers in the other domain without a problem too.

I'm using Powershell 3.0

Comment: Check your schema, and check if your PCs have OS fields populated.

Comment: Yep, the OS fields are populated in AD.  Like I said, I can get the right info if I am on the other domain; I get the Name, OperatingSystem and OperatingSystemValue all populated when I run this coimmand:


`Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties Name, OperatingSystem, OperatingSystemVersion | Format-Table Name, OperatingSystem, OperatingSystemVersion`

Comment: I just can't get the same info if I am on another domain (different AD admin account) running this command:

`Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties Name, OperatingSystem, OperatingSystemVersion -SearchBase "" -Server OtherDomain.com.au:3268 | Format-Table Name, OperatingSystem, OperatingSystemVersion`

Comment: Try this:  Get rid of the format-table.  Run it on a limited number (like 10) and Store the results in a variable.  Pass the variable to Get-Member to make sure that it's returning the properties you're asking for.  If so, the format-table part is messing you up.  If not, it may be that your account does not have enough permissions in OtherDomain to read attributes.

Comment: I managed to get it to work properly by changing the -searchbase and -server values:

`Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties Name, OperatingSystem, OperatingSystemVersion -SearchBase "DC=OtherDomain,DC=com,DC=au" -Server OtherDomain.com.au`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties Name, OperatingSystem, OperatingSystemVersion -SearchBase "DC=OtherDomain,DC=com,DC=au" -Server "OtherDomain.com.au" | Format-Table Name, OperatingSystem, OperatingSystemVersion
```

Had to include a value in the Searchbase parameter (cdidn't work with a null value) and remove the port number from the Server parameter value.